# Gerunds in the following sentences?

Tags: gerunds

I was pretty clear about Gerunds. But following two examples make me confused.

> he had a newspaper empire **backing** him

This example is from google translator https://translate.google.co.in/?um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#auto/en/back . They say "backing" is verb here. But i think "backing" is used here as a gerund(noun).

Another example

> I’ve been **dreaming** of summer all winter long

This example is from http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/gerunds/ (at the bottom). They say "dreaming" is gerund here. But i think it is a verb.

So are these examples are wrong  or am  I  missing something ?

Comment: They are both perfectly good, and neither of them contains a gerund. The first contains the _participle_ "backing" and the second you may analyse either as a participle, or more conventionally as the perfect of the progressive (or continuous) form of "dream": _I have been dreaming.

Comment: @ColinFine Can you please explain How "backing" is a participle . A participle is a word formed from a verb which can be used as an adjective.
So how "backing" is an adjective ? and which noun it is modifying?

Comment: "Backing him" is an adjectival phrase modifying "a newspaper empire". It may also be regarded as a [small clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_clause), corresponding to the full form "that was backing him"

Comment: Participles are verb forms, so the claim that "backing" and "dreaming" are verbs is reasonable.  They are not *finite* verbs, but they are still members of a verb's conjugation.  Since the present participle form and the gerund form are identical, there are some that use the "gerund" label even when the word takes a participial role, and there are others that use "gerund-participle" to cover all bases in all cases.  In short, Colin is absolutely correct, but that doesn't mean that Google or GingerSoftware is wrong.  They simply gave answers that were less complete and less useful than Colin's.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been dreaming

This example is not a gerund; it is the present perfect continuous of the verb "dream".